# to display dynamic form based on a paticular variable

Tags: java, html, plsql

SO , i have this issue where a requirement is to change HTML form(Which is being fetched from DB (form-section table)), and display it to participants . now there are two issues here i need to retain old form in the db for old participant and show new form to new user ,

second Issue is : for a single country i need to display two checkboxes, and for the rest of the world only one check box (without creating 2 form-sections).

Form is in html (no other language is allowed)  i know this is pretty easy with JSP

ANy help or the direction will be appreciated . :)

Answer (score 0):

All the possible forms should be on the DB, then you just have to change the stored procedure you use to fetch them.

Comment: Agreed, but changing stored procedure for them have high impact on other things, i tried with separate stored procedure for my requirement that too didn't solve my requirement of retaining both old and new form , also dynamic selection is not possible as i mentioned in the question that i need to select form based on a variable without creating new form section . Single form should do the job